# getAngularTestablilities method in deployment

Tags: angular

I am getting two methods in my window object after deploying the application in prod environment (getAngularTestablilities and getAllAngularTestabilities).

Is it normal to have such methods in deployment? How can I remove such methods from window objects?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems normal to have these methods in production because they are used by `e2e` test tool vendors like Protractor and the environment has to resemble production to ensure tests are effective.

And currently it seems that there's no way to disable them as they are added inside `initDomAdapter` application initializer:

```
export function initDomAdapter() {
  BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent();
  BrowserGetTestability.init();  <--------
}

export class BrowserGetTestability implements GetTestability {
  static init() { setTestabilityGetter(new BrowserGetTestability()); }

  addToWindow(registry: TestabilityRegistry): void {
    global['getAngularTestability'] = (elem: any, findInAncestors: boolean = true) => {
    ...
```

Of course you can manually assign them to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Hopefully we can create better build in future.

Comment: you're welcome, yeah, I'll update the question if I find out something new